# Use String like command in C

Tags: c, string, arduino-uno

I'm trying to use an SMS I send my Arduino as a command. The SMS message is a String, I cut away the front part and want to execute the new string called command like any other normal command.

```
if(message.indexOf("!C!") != -1 && message.indexOf("Change Var") != -1)
{
      command = message.substring(message.indexOf("Change Var") + 11);
      Serial.println(command);
      command;
}
```

So for example when I send the SMS:

!C! Change Var Serial.println("let's see what happens")

Only Serial.println("lets see what happens") is printed into command. I then want to execute that String called command so that lets see what happens is printed in my Debug Log. I hoped it would be as easy as you see above but sadly it doesn't work.

Is there a way to execute a String as a command?

Comment: You cannot execute a piece of C++ code stored in a string.

Comment: C (and C++, since Arduino environment is C++ based) are compiled languages. You cannot "inject" a line of code runtime and execute it like it was an interpreted language.

Comment: This question is similar to yours [Read a line of c code from file and execute in a c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541520/read-a-line-of-c-code-from-file-and-execute-in-a-c-program). The answers confirm what I wrote in my previous comment: bad news; you cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to do something like that in C would be to parse the scripted command by yourself.

In this case, the action (print) should be first separated from the value ("let's see what happens"). Then you can have a series of functions handling the supported actions and a main function dispatching to them, for instance in a switch statement :

```
enum ScriptActions {
    PrintAction = 1,
    //other actions
} 

switch(action) {

    case PrintAction: puts(strValue); break;
    //other actions

    default: printf("This action is not supported\n");
}
```

The parsing part producing `action` and `strValue` (and possibly other kind of values) should be done before that step and it should contain a strict error handling to avoid for the actions to be called with some wrong parameters.